# function overloading for displaying different number types

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I'm trying to make a program with an overloaded function "display". So far I've been ok, but I seem to be stuck. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with my code here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()


{
    double small_num, large_num;
    double display;//I think the problem is here!!!

    cout <<"Please enter two number starting with the smallest, then enter the      largest"<<endl;

cin >> small_num;
cin >> large_num;
display(small_num, large_num);



system("pause");
return 0;
}

void display(int num1, int num2)
{
    cout << num1 <<" "<< num2 << endl;
    return;
}

void display(double num1, int num2)
{
    cout << num1 <<" "<< num2 << endl;
}

void display(int num1, double num2)
{
    cout << num1 <<" "<< num2 << endl;
}

void display(double num1, double num2)
{
    cout << num1 <<" "<< num2 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `double display;`. This creates a new local variable named `display`, which conflicts with your function names.

And also either:

- Put the `display` methods above `main`.
- Leave their definitions where they are and declare them above main as follows:

  ```
  void display(int num1, int num2);
  void display(double num1, int num2);
  void display(int num1, double num2);
  void display(double num1, double num2);
  ```